# Anchor build error versions of anchor-spl and anchor-lang

Tags: rust, anchor, rust-cargo, solana

I'm using the following repository of rust:

https://github.com/SmartCodeBlockchainDev/Nelson-NFT-stacking

when I try to do an anchor build I get the following error:

```
Failed to obtain package metadata: `cargo metadata` exited with an error:     Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `anchor-lang = "^0.20.1"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.24.2
location searched: crates.io index
required by package `nft-staking v0.1.0 (/staking/programs/staking)`
```

And when I update the cargo.toml file to those versions (anchor-lang and anchor-spl 0.24.2) it gives me several errors in lib.rs:

```
error: bump targets should not be provided with init. Please use bump without a target.
   --> programs/staking/src/lib.rs:582:9
    |
582 |         bump = vault_nonce,
    |         ^^^^

error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate`
  --> programs/staking/src/lib.rs:48:1
   |
48 | #[program]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^ could not find `__client_accounts_create_user` in the crate root
   |
   = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: cannot find attribute `error` in this scope
    --> programs/staking/src/lib.rs:1024:3
     |
1024 | #[error]
     |   ^^^^^
     |
note: `error` is imported here, but it is a function-like macro
    --> programs/staking/src/lib.rs:2:5
     |
2    | use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: cannot find attribute `msg` in this scope
    --> programs/staking/src/lib.rs:1026:7
     |
1026 |     #[msg("Insufficient funds to unstake.")]
     |       ^^^
     |
note: `msg` is imported here, but it is a function-like macro
    --> programs/staking/src/lib.rs:2:5
     |
2    | use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

note: `msg` is imported here, but it is a function-like macro
    --> programs/staking/src/lib.rs:2:5
     |
2    | use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: cannot find attribute `msg` in this scope
    --> programs/staking/src/lib.rs:1030:7
     |
1030 |     #[msg("Reward B cannot be funded - pool is single stake.")]
     |       ^^^
     |
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

```
note: `msg` is imported here, but it is a function-like macro
    --> programs/staking/src/lib.rs:2:5
     |
2    | use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

warning: unused import: `program_option::COption`
 --> programs/staking/src/lib.rs:3:42
  |
3 | use anchor_lang::solana_program::{clock, program_option::COption};
  |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `try_accounts` found for struct `InitializePool` in the current scope
   --> programs/staking/src/lib.rs:48:1
    |
48  | #[program]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `InitializePool<'_>`
...
539 | pub struct InitializePool<'info> {
    | -------------------------------- function or associated item `try_accounts` not found for this
    |
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
    = note: the following trait defines an item `try_accounts`, perhaps you need to implement it:
            candidate #1: `anchor_lang::Accounts`
    = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound `InitializePool<'_>: anchor_lang::Accounts<'_>` is not satisfied
  --> programs/staking/src/lib.rs:48:1
   |
48 | #[program]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `anchor_lang::Accounts<'_>` is not implemented for `InitializePool<'_>`
   |
note: required by `anchor_lang::context::Context::<'a, 'b, 'c, 'info, T>::new`
  --> /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/anchor-lang-0.24.2/src/context.rs:51:5
   |
51 | /     pub fn new(
52 | |         program_id: &'a Pubkey,
53 | |         accounts: &'b mut T,
54 | |         remaining_accounts: &'c [AccountInfo<'info>],
55 | |         bumps: BTreeMap<String, u8>,
56 | |     ) -> Self {
   | |_____________^
   = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0599]: no method named `exit` found for struct `InitializePool` in the current scope
   --> programs/staking/src/lib.rs:48:1
    |
48  | #[program]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `InitializePool<'_>`
...
539 | pub struct InitializePool<'info> {
    | -------------------------------- method `exit` not found for this
    |
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
    = note: the following trait defines an item `exit`, perhaps you need to implement it:
            candidate #1: `anchor_lang::AccountsExit`
    = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `try_accounts` found for struct `CreateUser` in the current scope
   --> programs/staking/src/lib.rs:48:1
    |
48  | #[program]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `CreateUser<'_>`
...
608 | pub struct CreateUser<'info> {
    | ---------------------------- function or associated item `try_accounts` not found for this
    |
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
    = note: the following trait defines an item `try_accounts`, perhaps you need to implement it:
            candidate #1: `anchor_lang::Accounts`
    = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound `CreateUser<'_>: anchor_lang::Accounts<'_>` is not satisfied
  --> programs/staking/src/lib.rs:48:1
   |
48 | #[program]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `anchor_lang::Accounts<'_>` is not implemented for `CreateUser<'_>`
   |
note: required by `anchor_lang::context::Context::<'a, 'b, 'c, 'info, T>::new`
  --> /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/anchor-lang-0.24.2/src/context.rs:51:5
   |
51 | /     pub fn new(
52 | |         program_id: &'a Pubkey,
53 | |         accounts: &'b mut T,
54 | |         remaining_accounts: &'c [AccountInfo<'info>],
55 | |         bumps: BTreeMap<String, u8>,
56 | |     ) -> Self {
   | |_____________^
   = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0599]: no method named `exit` found for struct `CreateUser` in the current scope
   --> programs/staking/src/lib.rs:48:1
    |
48  | #[program]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `CreateUser<'_>`
...
608 | pub struct CreateUser<'info> {
    | ---------------------------- method `exit` not found for this
    |
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
    = note: the following trait defines an item `exit`, perhaps you need to implement it:
            candidate #1: `anchor_lang::AccountsExit`
    = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `program` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0599]: no variant or associated item named `NotFoundCandyMachine` found for enum `anchor_lang::error::ErrorCode` in the current scope
   --> programs/staking/src/lib.rs:214:35
    |
214 |             return Err(ErrorCode::NotFoundCandyMachine.into());
    |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ variant or associated item not found in `anchor_lang::error::ErrorCode`

error[E0599]: no variant or associated item named `PoolPaused` found for enum `anchor_lang::error::ErrorCode` in the current scope
   --> programs/staking/src/lib.rs:224:35
    |
224 |             return Err(ErrorCode::PoolPaused.into());
    |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^ variant or associated item not found in `anchor_lang::error::ErrorCode`

error[E0599]: no variant or associated item named `CandyNotMatch` found for enum `anchor_lang::error::ErrorCode` in the current scope
   --> programs/staking/src/lib.rs:250:35
    |
250 |             return Err(ErrorCode::CandyNotMatch.into());
    |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ variant or associated item not found in `anchor_lang::error::ErrorCode`

error[E0599]: no variant or associated item named `CandyNotMatch` found for enum `anchor_lang::error::ErrorCode` in the current scope
   --> programs/staking/src/lib.rs:331:35
    |
331 |             return Err(ErrorCode::CandyNotMatch.into());
    |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ variant or associated item not found in `anchor_lang::error::ErrorCode`

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0432, E0599.
```

Comment: I've changed [#error] for [#error_code] and  several errors have been fixed

Comment: Thank you. Cannot believe the official documentation doesn't mention anything about this https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/0.20.1/anchor_lang/attr.error.html

Answer (score 2):

It's because all older versions of the anchor are yanked:
https://crates.io/crates/anchor-lang/versions

You can force required version by git tag in your Cargo.toml:

```
anchor-lang = { git = "https://github.com/project-serum/anchor", tag = "v0.20.1" }
```

But there can be security issues if older versions of the anchor have vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You have to downgrade the anchor version to `0.21.0`

If you are on a windows machine, you can simply use `npm i -g @project-serum/anchor-cli@^0.21.0`

But if you are on WSL or Ubuntu you have to run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install -y pkg-config build-essential libudev-dev`

Then build specific version from source using `cargo install --git https://github.com/project-serum/anchor --tag v0.21.0 anchor-cli --locked`

Remember you should have to `cargo` installed to run this command

If the problem persists,your `~/.cargo/registry/index` directory is corrupted. Delete it and run `cargo update` again."

For opening it in WSL, just type `explorer.exe .` in the ubuntu terminal

Don't forget the `.`

Comment: I've done this and doesn't work, my versions are : anchor-cli 0.20.0, solana 1.9.4, cargo, 1.60.0 and I've deleted .cargo/registry/index, but the error persist: candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.24.2
location searched: crates.io index

Comment: do u found the solution yet? @VictorFernandez

Answer (score 0):

```
cargo install --git https://github.com/project-serum/anchor --tag v0.24.2 anchor-cli --locked
```

Then in the cargo.toml of the projects folder, make your anchor-lang=0.24.2
instead 0.20.1

I was having the same issue and this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It is no advisable to delete your  *.cargo/registry/index* it can break your cargo if you are not careful just downgrade or upgrade with: ***cargo install --git https://github.com/project-serum/anchor --tag v0.21.0 anchor-cli --locked*** then specify to the version you want.

Answer (score 0):

For my Mac the following command worked for me. It should also work on Ubuntu and wsl 2 on windows.

```
cargo install --git https://github.com/project-serum/anchor --tag v0.21.0 anchor-cli --locked --force
```

Answer (score 0):

**This Worked for me**
I uninstall the anchor cli and reinstall the version 0.27.0 using cargo like this;

> cargo uninstall anchor-cli

and then

> cargo install anchor-cli --version 0.27.0